# Java Substring Missing Character?

Tags: java, syntax, numbers, substring

I'm having an issue with the following code and I'm not sure where to even start:

```
                System.out.println("Subject: " + message.getSubject());
                subjectPack = message.getSubject().replaceAll("([,|!|@|$|&|%|^|*|;|:|<|>|\"|\'|(|)|/|\\|+])", "").replaceAll("[.](?![\\w]{2,4}$)", "").replaceAll("( )+|(\t)", " ");
                System.out.println("Subject Line Length: " + subjectPack.length());
                System.out.println("Subject: " + subjectPack);

                subjectPack = subjectPack.toUpperCase().substring(message.getSubject().lastIndexOf("#")+1).toUpperCase();
                System.out.println("PO Length: " + subjectPack.length());
                System.out.println("PO: " + subjectPack);
              subjectPack = subjectPack.substring(0,6);
```

And it works fine several other examples except this one.. why is it kicking the "1"?

```
Subject: FW: Freight shifted on Turbana Load Po#160753
Subject Line Length: 44
Subject: FW Freight shifted on Turbana Load Po#160753
PO Length: 5
PO: 60753
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String ind
ex out of range: 6
        at java.lang.String.substring(Unknown Source)
        at picRead.PictureReader.sendmsg(PictureReader.java:191)
        at picRead.PictureReader.main(PictureReader.java:116)
```

Comment: if `subjectPack` is only length 5, then you can't access index location 6.

Comment: Right, but it should be pulling 160753, not 60753.

Comment: Why are you getting the `lastIndexOf` based on `message.getSubject()` and not `subjectPack`?

Comment: `subjectPack` does not have a ":", but you are using `message.getSubject().lastIndexOf("#")+1` and `message.getSubject()` does have the semi-colon.

Comment: sorry for misunderstanding; it's because you've stripped the colon ":" (as @JohnnyMopp points out) but the code does not update the index location for the "#".  The string has shortened by length 1 and so you are missing the first character (happens to be a "1" in this case).

Comment: Thanks Adam and all. I was overlooking that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are extracting the PO from `subjectPack` but determine the starting position from `message.getSubject()`

```
    subjectPack.substring(message.getSubject().lastIndexOf("#")+1).toUpperCase();
//                        ^ you determine the starting position here
//  ^ you are extracting from this string

// "FW: Freight shifted on Turbana Load Po#160753"
// "FW Freight shifted on Turbana Load Po#160753"
//  you are extracting from ...            ^ this position
```

---

On a side note: you don't need to call `.toUpperCase()` twice - either before or after the `.substring()` operation is sufficient.

Comment: This was the answer. Thanks!